# Category is equivalent to the colimit of its finite subcategories and colimit in Cat

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, equivalence-of-categories

$\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}$Let $I$ be a (small) category, and take $S(I)$ to be the poset of finite subcategories of $I$, ordered by inclusion, treated as a category. One can show $S(I)$ turns out to be filtered (EDIT: not true, see below). This gives a functor $S(I)\to Cat$ sending a subcategory $I'$ to itself seen as category in its own right. We can look at the colimit of that functor (assuming it exists, I think it does, thanks to some result I do not know about small colimits in $Cat$)

I'm fairly confident that the canonical morphism $f:\colim_{I'\in S(I)}I'\to I$ is an equivalence of categories. This is very reminiscent of say "a module is isomorphic to the filtered colimit of its finite type submodule" or "a set is isomorphic to the filtered colimit of its finite subset". But in that case, I'm not sure how to proceed, because I don't really know how to handle colimits in $Cat$, my intuition breaks down so to speak.

I think I can show $f$ to be essentially surjective (see below), but I don't know how to proceed onwards and prove it's fully faithful. Producing a functor in the other direction and the required natural isomorphisms seems quite a bit harder, so I'd rather stick to showing it's fully faithful.

For the essential surjectivity, take $A\in I$ then $A\in I'$ for some finite subcategory of $I$, hence we get an objet of $\colim_{I'\in S(I)}I'$ by looking at the image of $A$ via the canonical morphism $\iota_{I'}:I'\to\colim_{J\in S(I)}J$, i.e. $\iota_{I'}(A)$. We then have $A\simeq f(\iota_{I'}(A))$.

It would now suffice to show $\hom_{\colim_{I'\in S(I)}I'}(A,B)\simeq \hom_{I}(fA,fB)$. But I have no idea what the first hom-set looks like.

EDIT : As @AlexKruckman pointed out in the comments, as stated, there is an issue. I said at the beginning "One can show $S(I)$ turns out to be filtered", but this is not the case. As he mentioned, this fails to be true for instance when considering a free product $G*H$ with $G,H$ finite and non trivial. So one should replace "finite" with finitely generated here.

Comment: Is $f$ an _isomorphism_ of categories (with a strict inverse)?

Comment: Surely you want to consider the *finitely generated* subcategories, not the finite subcategories.

Comment: It is not true that the finite subcategories of a category form a filtered diagram. Consider the free product of two finite non-trivial groups, viewed as a $1$-object category.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm not sure what I want to be honest, I saw this as an exercise awhile back and I'm trying to remember where from because I'm not sure of the precise statement that the exercise was asking to prove, but I seem to recall the author did say finite, as in finite set of objects and morphisms. But your comment suggests that I should actually want finitely generated I suppose.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I haven't given that much thought, I feel like it might be yes, but I don't know. But isomorphism of categories are rare so maybe not. Off the top of my head I don't know.

Comment: Perhaps the precise statement you want to prove is that the category of small categories is [locally finitely presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+finitely+presentable+category)?

Comment: @varkor I eventually was able to locate where I had seen that exercise, and the goal was to show that a category admits all colimits if and only if it has all filtered colimits and finite colimits. One was supposed to deduce the previous statement from the statement of my question (the map $colim I' \to I$ being an equivalence and $S(I)$ being filtered).

Comment: @notananalyst And where was it that you saw the exercise? A more straightforward way to show that having all filtered colimits and finite colimits implies having all colimits is to observe that if you have all finite colimits, you have all coequalizers and all finite coproducts, and an arbitrary coproduct is a filtered colimit of finite coproducts. So you have all coproducts and coequalizers. And then prove that this is sufficient for having all colimits.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how that exercise could have been supposed to work. A category is the *directed* colimit of its finitely generated subcategories and the *filtered* colimit of its category of maps from finitely *presented* categories (not subcategories.) I guess the latter is closer: if you have finitely presented colimits and filtered colimits, etc...Still seems like a weird thing to talk about.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I found it in a set of exercises a prof had sent me via email, exercises they had written for a class that used to exist in my university a few years back.